# load url image swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

How do I get images from a URL (which is in a json string to load in an `UIImageView`)?

I have named the view as `imageurl` to make it reflect the same name as the json string - I know that is not the error.

```
 let url = URL(string: nowplaying.data[0].track.imageurl)
 let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
 self.imageurl.image = UIImage(data: data!)
```

Comment: Does the URL reference a local file or do you have to retrieve it over the internet? If it's the latter, you need to make an async call. Personally, I prefer using Kingfisher and calling it a day.

Comment: trying with Kingfisher but the latest version is giving errors Thread 16: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Kingfisher`, you can load image from url asynchronously.

```
if var strUrl = nowplaying.data.first?.track.imageurl, strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {

    self.imageurl.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl), placeholder: nil)

}
```

it will load image from url asynchronously without blocking main thread.

**correction**

```
if var strUrl = nowplaying.data.first?.track.imageurl {

   strUrl = strUrl.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)!
     self.imageurl.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: strUrl), placeholder: nil)

}
```

Comment: why so? what is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: Cannot assign to value: 'strUrl' is a 'let' constant

Comment: just make it `var`

Comment: Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'

Comment: its done now...just need to safely unwrap the optional